# Android location service city name

Tags: java, android

I am using android locations in marshmallow. I use the code below to find the city at the current location. But for some reason when I test the app in my car and go anywhere over 40mph, the city name disappears from my text view, and then appears if I bring my speed down in the car or am stationary. I'm not sure why. My latitude and longitude are ok it's just something is wrong with a city name coming up at higher speeds. Any suggestion would help. Thanks...

```
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    globalLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    globalLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    Log.i("Latitude", globalLatitude.toString());
    Log.i("Longitude", globalLongitude.toString());


    try {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(globalLatitude, globalLongitude, 1);
        String locationLump = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
        //calling my method
        returningResultFromZipCodeCutting = gettingRidOfZipCode(locationLump);
        mCurrentLocation.setText(returningResultFromZipCodeCutting);



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

p.s. gettingRidOfZipCode(locationLump) just cuts away the zip code from the city and return just the city and the state in a returningResultFromZipCodeCutting.

Comment: Try to use `geocoder.isPresent()` to see if you have a problem eith your connection when the name disappears.

Comment: geocoder.isPresent() shows true when the name disappears.

Comment: Never mind I solved it. It's a problem with the Geocoder. When you are going over 40mph it switches things around...

Comment: Can you elborate please? It might be useful for others too.